# AngularJS filters - search multiple fields

Tags: javascript, angularjs, search

What I am trying to do is search by multiple fields of a repeat in combination. The issue is when I search by `query.$` model I can't search from multiple fields.

What I'm looking for is to search for 1234 + Street Name

```
<input ng-keypress="searching()" type="text" ng-model="query.$" placeholder="Search" />

<li ng-repeat="item in (filteredItems = (items| filter:query))">
     {{item.address.streetNumber}} {{item.address.streetName}}
</li>
```

I found a [set of filters](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) which I thought would work but not sure I'm using this right.

```
filterBy: ['item.address.streetNumber' + 'item.address.streetName']: query
```

Any help appreciated. Here is what I have done.
http://plnkr.co/edit/75nGxVgqL3lJVFlGyZMY?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

using a predicate function is one way, see: http://ngtutorial.com/learn/filter.html#/_tblcontents_20

**update**

please tell me if that example does not explain it properly, thanks.

**Update, add example**

return 'true' if you wanted the item.

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.predfn = function(v) {
    return v.name == '123' || v.phone == 'Fake Street';
  };
```

...

```
 <tr ng-repeat="friendObj in friends | filter:predfn">
```

Comment: Thanks, but not sure if I understand or this is what I need. Take a look at the link.

http://plnkr.co/edit/75nGxVgqL3lJVFlGyZMY?p=preview

Comment: updated to give an example, return true if you wanted the item.

Comment: try to avoid using '$' in the filter Filter, because this will try to search every property.